# Вы "разочарованны"?

Tags: орфография

Разочарованны? Какое количество "Н" пишется?

Answer (score 3):

Вы про Н / НН ?  Если это краткое прилагательное - -НН-: Вы каковы? - разочарованны.(Она вся выражает разочарование)

Если причастие - -Н- : Вы (каковы? что сделаны?) разочарованы (чем?-этой ситуацией)
Чаще употребляется как причастие -разочарована чем-то, в ком-то.
Вопросительная интонация в данном случае,по-моему, уточняет значение  действия, это скорее
причастие, чем прилагательное. Значит, одно -Н-.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что в языке есть только причастие страдательного залога прошедшего времени полное разочароваННый (< от глагола  разочаровать) и краткое разочароваН — разочароваНы (мн. ч.) с одной буквой -Н- согласно общему правилу написания кратких страдательных причастий. В имя прилагательное это причастие перейти не может, поскольку у него пока сохраняются сильные связи с исходным глаголом — семантика, значения вида, времени и др.
   Поэтому только разочароваНы (краткое причастие).

Comment: Орфографический словарь даёт и причастие:разочарованный разочар`ованный; кр. ф. -ан, -ана и прилагательное:(обнаруживающий, выражающий разочарование) -ан, -анна (он`а грустн`а и разочар`ованна)
http://poiskslov.com/word/ Ожегов 1977 года тоже. Видимо, это вопрос стилистики, что чаще употребляется полная форма прилагательного, но далеко не все учёные отрицают использование краткой формы.Рядом с другим кратким прилагательным и очарованна смотрится нормально.

Comment: Т.Ефремова тоже признаёт прилагательным: Новый толково-словообразовательный словарь русского языка. Автор Т. Ф. Ефремова.
разочарованный прил. 1) Находящийся в состоянии глубокого разочарования; изверившийся в ком-л., чем- л. 2) Выражающий разочарование (по той же ссылке)